# SonarQube exclude auto generate files based on content

Tags: c#, regex, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I am having a bit of an issue with excluding auto-generated files when using MSbuild runner.

Each file that is auto generate has  within. I have gone into sonarQube setting for project and set the "Ignore Issues on Files" to =

> `.*<auto-generated>.*`

the job builds using msbuild but doesn't ignore files and still calls out issues.

It's driving me mad!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. The match on exclusions is performed on a full file path so you'd better set `sonar.exclusions=**/.*auto-generated.*`.
   That will guarantee that file matching **auto-generated** in ANY directory will be ignored. (Note: I don't know if the `<>`are part of your desired regexp or not.
   See http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-patterns on the usage of patterns.
2. Where/How did you set the exclusions to avoid scanning auto generated files ?

The simplest way is to pass this exclusion to the MSBuild Runner (Begin) command line with option `/d:"sonar.exclusions=.*auto-generated.*"`